# How to implement inverse cosine in react js without using math library?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

How can I use inverse cosine here?

```
const volumeCalculator = () => {
    const dens = tank.density;
    const lHeight = pressure / (dens * 9.81);
    // const resHeight = tank.height - lHeight;
    const len = tank.length;
    const rad = tank.radius;
    const circum = 3.1416 * (rad ** 2);
    if (tank.vertical === 'Vertical') {
      const volume = circum * lHeight;
      return volume;
    }
    const volume = [Math.acos((rad - lHeight) / rad)(rad * 2) - (rad - lHeight) * Math.sqrt(2 * rad * lHeight - (lHeight * 2))] * len;
    return volume;
  };
```

I am expecting inverse cosine result on a number.

Comment: Note that you are multiplying an array and a value: `const volume = [ ..... ] * len;`. Assuming that what is inside of the brackets produces a *number*, then due to peculiarities of JS this will work.... but it does not seem right. Also note that `Math.acos` expects a number parameter that should be between `-1` and `1` (inclusive).

Comment: Third note: what is the part `((rad - lHeight) / rad)(rad * 2)` supposed to mean? E.g. if I do `(5+1)(2)` then I get `Uncaught TypeError: 6 is not a function`.